# Robot Framework - SSH library - Editing a file on remote server

Tags: ssh, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary, robotframework-pythonremoteserver

I am writing a test case in Robot Framework where in, I have to either copy the file from the local machine (windows) to the remote server (linux) or create a new one at the location.
I have used multiple `sudo su -` command to switch users to ***root user*** to reach the desired host. As a result of this, I am not able to use `Put File` Keyword from `SSH Library` to upload the file.  I have reached at the desired folder location by executing the commands with `Write` keyword.
Since there is no option left (thats what i realize with my limited knowledge on Robot Framework), i started creating a new file with `vi <filename>` command. I have also reached the INSERT mode of the file, ***BUT*** i am not able to edit text into the file.

Can someone please suggest me how can i either

1. Copy the file from local windows machine to remote linux server AFTER multiple SU commands (Switch User)
2. Create a new text file and enter the content.

Please See : the new file which is being created / copied is a certificate file. Hence i do not wish to write the entire content of the certificate in my test suite file

The entire test case looks something like this

```
First Jump1
    Log    Starting the connection to AWS VM
    # Connection to VM with Public Key
    Connection To VM    ${hostname}    ${username} 
    Send Command    sudo su -
    Send Command    su - <ServiceUser1>
    # Reached the Detination server
    Send Command    whoami  
    Send Command    ss -tln | grep 127.0.0.1:40
    # Connecting to Particular ZIP
    Send Command    sudo -u <ServiceUser2> /usr/bin/ssh <ServiceUser2>@localhost -p <port>
    Send Command    sudo su -
    # Check Auth Certificate
    Send Command    mosquitto_pub -h ${mq_host} -p ${mq_port} -u ${mq_username} -P ${mq_password}
```

In the step **Check Auth Certificate**, the certificate is checked to be present or not, if present -> delete the current certificate and create the new one (either create a new file or upload from local) and if it not there create a new certificate

Comment: why do you need multiple sudo su commands? can you elaborate more on how you connect to the desired location

Comment: Because, our team does not have the public & private key to connect with the destination host with the service / technical user. Hence have to connect with our individual users and then `sudo su` commands

Comment: what i meant was, how many connections do you need to make, where do you need to switch the user etc...

Comment: @JiriJanous its 3 connections - the test case is updated in the question

Comment: You could copy the file with scp with your login user (even to /tmp), then su, copy it locally to the destination folder and change its ownership as needed.

Comment: tried doing this, but got struck at the last step due to lack of permission to do SCP or SFTP and also existence of firewall between the 2 host machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though it might not be ideal, but was able to achieve what i wanted to do with

```
echo "content" > newFilename
echo "update content" >> newFileName
```